Given $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.If $B=\{T\subseteq A$ such that $1\notin T$ or $2\in T\}$ .Then find $n(B\cup C)$.
Given $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.
If $B=\{T\subseteq A$ such that $1\notin T$ or $2\in T\}$ and
$C=\{T\subseteq A$ such that sum of elements of T is a prime number}
Then find $n(B\cup C)$.
My Attempt
Clearly $n(B)=n(1\notin A)+n(2\in A)-n((1\notin A)\cap(2\in A))=2^6+2^6-2^5=96$
Can $n(C)$ be found by a shorter method or $C$ has to be found manually considering the cases where the sum of elements is $2,3,5,7,9,11,13,17,19$ after which we have to find $B\cap C$

Answer is $|C|=42$ and $|B\cup C|=107$, for when you do find a solution. I can't see any method that avoids considering a bunch of cases.

I am getting 41 cases for $C$ viz. ${2},{3},{1,2},{5},{1,4},{2,3},{7},{1,6},{2,5},{3,4},{1,2,4},{4,72},{4,2,5},{1,4,6},{5,6},{1,3,7},{2,3,6},{1,2,3,5},{6,7},{1,5,7},{2,4,7},{2,5,6},{3,4,6},{1,2,4,6},{1,3,4,5},{4,6,7},{2,3,5,7},{1,3,6,7},{1,4,5,7},{2,4,5,6},{1,2,3,4,7},{1,2,3,5,6},{1,2,3,6,7},{1,2,4,5,7},{1,3,4,5,6},{3,4,5,7},{1,5,6,7},{2,4,6,7},{1,2,3,4,6,7},{1,4,5,6,7},{2,3,5,6,7}$. What am I missing

Probably ${}$ (which you included in your count for $B$ for what it's worth)

Note that $n(B\cup C) = 2^7-|\{T\subseteq A | 1, 2\in T, \text{sum of elements of }T\text{ is composite}\}|$. Next $$|\{T\subseteq A | 1, 2\in T, \text{sum of elements of }T\text{ is composite}\}| $$ $$= 2^5-|\{T\subseteq A | 1, 2\in T, \text{sum of elements of }T\text{ is prime}\}|$$
Thus
$$n(B\cup C) = 2^7-2^5+|\{T\subseteq A | 1, 2\in T, \text{sum of elements of }T\text{ is prime}\}|$$
We do casework by what the prime sum could be and, ignoring $1, 2\in T$ for compactness, we get
$$ T = \{4\}$$
$$ T = \{3, 5\}$$
$$ T = \{3, 7\},\{4, 6\} $$
$$ T = \{3, 4, 7\},\{3, 5, 6\}$$
$$ T = \{3, 6, 7\},\{4, 5, 7\}$$
$$ T = \{3, 4, 6, 7\},$$
so $n(B\cup C) = 128-32+9 = 105?$. Let me know if I missed a $T$ above.

(5,7) and (3,4,5,6) are clearly missing

1+2+5+7 = 15, 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21. These are not prime.
